# Time on Rails baseball schedule app off by 5 hours on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I have an app: http://arethebaronsplaying.com/ that breaks everyday at 7pm US Central time on production, but works correctly locally. The site is hosted by Ninefold.

In short, I have a seeds.rb file with a bunch of Game objects, and one of the attributes for a Game is date, which is set to the m/d format, ex. 4/09.

And every day at 7pm the app breaks by displaying a big NO and text saying when the next game is, and the next game is the current day's game. Then below that, it will display a YES! with the current day's game.

So it's displaying a YES and a NO, which makes me think that perhaps `Date.today` is calculating time differently than `Time.now`, and since I'm using both of them, the one that is wrong will display the NO.

Anyway, here's my logic:

```
<% i = 0 %>
<% games.each do |game| %>
<% if game.date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] == Time.now.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] && game.away == false %>
<h1 class="main-text answer yesanswer" id="responsive_headline"><%=link_to "YES!", "http://www.milb.com/tickets/singlegame.jsp?sid=t247", target: "_blank" %></h1>
<% i = 1 %>
<br>
<h2 class="main-text2 gamewrap" id="responsive_headline2">
    <% if game.away == false %>
        <span class="next-venue">vs.</span>
        <span class="next-opponent"><%= game.opponent %></span> |
        <span class="next-time"><%= game.time %></span>
    <% else %>
        <span class="next-venue">at</span>
        <span class="next-opponent"><%= game.opponent %></span> |
        <span class="next-time"><%= game.time %></span>
    <% end %>
</h2>
<% elsif game.date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] == Time.now.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] && game.away == true %>
    <% unless i == 1 %>
    <a><h1 class="main-text answer" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal id="responsive_headline">NO.</h1></a>
    <% i = 1 %>
    <h2 class="main-text2 gamewrap" id="responsive_headline2">
        <span class="next-venue">away game</span>
        <span class="next-opponent">@<%= game.opponent %></span>
    </h2>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <% unless i == 1 %>
    <a><h1 class="main-text answer" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal id="responsive_headline">NO.</h1></a>
    <% i = 1 %>
    <h2 class="main-text2 gamewrap" id="responsive_headline2">
        <span class="next-venue">vs.</span>
        <span class="next-opponent">
            <% if next_home_game > 1 %>
            <%= game.opponent %>
            in <%= next_home_game %> days |
            <% else %>
            <%= game.opponent %>
            in <%= next_home_game %> day |
            <% end %>
        <span class="next-time"><%= game.time %></span>
    </h2>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried adding `config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'` to both `application.rb` and `production.rb` and it broke the deployment.

Here's how Ninefold does Time: https://help.ninefold.com/hc/en-us/articles/201320124-What-time-standard-does-Ninefold-use-

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Dates and times (across timezones) are a nightmare to manage (I know that's not much help... but I've been there and you have my condolences).

Anyway... try replacing all of your `Time.now` and `Date.today` calls with `Time.zone.now` and `Time.zone.today` respectively.

Ensure all of your times are stored in the DB in UTC (no matter what your local time, or the server's time) and check out some articles that give other advice (like http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails and http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll definitely try that. I don't have any times stored in the database, just dates (4/11), should I change those at all?